# I am having trouble with regex, I am not sure why it does not work

Tags: java, regex

Can anyone help me convert this regex into Java? I am not sure why it is not working, I have read the documentation and made it for Java, but it doesn't work with Java. However, it works on a Perl regex testing website just fine.

```
(.*?);[01]:
```

And I basically have this:

```
expiem;0:2pfemfrance;1:runiora;1:stallker420;1:phoenixblaze0916;1:myothorax;1
```

All I want to do is get a list of the names `expiem`, `2pfemfrance`, etc. into a string array

Yes, here is my code: where the `builder.toString()` contains what I mentioned

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("h=(.*)");
Matcher match = pattern.matcher(builder.toString());
if( match.find() ) {
    this.userlist = match.group(1).split("(.*?);[01]:");                              
    this.loaded = true;
    this.index = 0;
}
```

By the way, `match.group(1)` is the exact string I posted, it is exactly

```
expiem;0:2pfemfrance;1:runiora;1:stallker420;1:phoenixblaze0916;1:myothorax;1
```

(I tested it by printing it out on the console)

Comment: Could you post what you have already tried to do? I.e. the actual Java code where you are trying to use the regex.

Comment: This will not hit the complete string, only parts of the string, so depending on where you put that regexp you will have less or more success. show a little bit more about the code you use

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the string capture to be part of your split expression: it will eat up your string.

You state that the perl version works, however that requires that the input string ends with a `:`. If it doesn't, you need to add a `?` after to the `:` to specify that it is optional.

Try:

```
this.userlist = match.group(1).split(";[01]:?");
```

Comment: Dont you need an additional `?` at the end to get rid of the very last `;1`?

Comment: @ValarDohaeris Note that OP does not have an `:` at the end of the input string, while your code has

Answer (score 1):

With this code

```
String input = "h=expiem;0:2pfemfrance;1:runiora;1:stallker420;1:phoenixblaze0916;1:myothorax;1";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("h=(.*)");
Matcher match = pattern.matcher(input);
if( match.find() ) {
   String substr = match.group(1);
   System.out.println(substr);

   String[] userlist = substr.split(";[01]:?");
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(userlist));
}
```

you get

```
expiem;0:2pfemfrance;1:runiora;1:stallker420;1:phoenixblaze0916;1:myothorax;1
[expiem, 2pfemfrance, runiora, stallker420, phoenixblaze0916, myothorax]
```

The relevant regexp to split the string is **`";[01]:?"`**

Answer (score 0):

```
String names = "expiem;0:2pfemfrance;1:runiora;1:stallker420;1:phoenixblaze0916;1:myothorax;1"
String[] nameArray = names.split(":");

List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String name : nameArray) {
    String[] tupel = name.split(";");
    nameList.add(tupel[0]);
}
```

Well it is not a cool regex solution but imo easy to understand. Basically you split the long string into smaller strings which are separated by :

Then you split the small strings using the separator ; and add the first entry of that result (which is the name) to a list.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

- your regex is *capturing* your target - the regex should be for the *separators*, not the content you want to keep
- you have waaay too much code. You only need one line!

Try this:

```
String[] names = builder.toString().split(";[01]:");
```